# Run some code at server start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, server, boot

I have some code I'd like to run that mangles some data structure and makes the result available to one or more controllers.

The data and conversion process are essentially hard codedso the output will be the same for the entire uptime of the server (but large enough to impose multiple seconds of processing time each time the conversion occurs) .

My question is, in rails, where's the best place to call this code from and the best way to make the result available to all controllers? The resulting data structure is read-only so I'm not worried about multiple threads accessing the data (ie: you can think of this as a hash of hashes, arrays and simple, thread-safe objects).

Since the result is basically static, it seems wasteful in terms of network resources and processing time to stick it in a database, so I was wondering what the best way is to have this data object setup once inside the server and available to all controllers?

If this were going into a heavy-production system, I'd have a backend job generate the data and stick it in some cache servers (memcache, in-memory redis, etc), but for smaller projects, I was wondering if there was a way to do this without resorting to storing it externally to the rails server itself or rebuilding the data object every time a controller neads it.

*This question is based on a problem I've had to solve in prior years in a different development language and was curious how to handle it in the rails 3/4 world.*

Comment: You could probably run some code in your initialisers folder that does this on server startup. Maybe in a module or singleton. This would be availabile across the application. It isn't great practice to expose things globally. I think rails has a built in cache that you could use as well.